# Get Observable is not sent to the backend

Tags: angular, observable

I am using this angular front end code to send to net core:

```
  public getStock(name: string) : Observable<Cagr[]>{
// url should be api/stock/aapl
const url = `${this.apiURL}/api/stock/${name}`;
console.log('url', url)
return this.Icagr$ = this.http.get<Cagr[]>(url);
```

}

The url is displayed correctly in the console window. When I click on the url in the console window the correct site is displayed. I am not able to get my code to access the backend. I put in a breakpoint on the get backend. It does not get there after I input the stock.

This is the component code:

```
    get(stock) {
  this.api.getStock(stock);
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you don't subscribe to the observable, it will never run. `this.api.getStock(stock).subscribe(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont have any CORS or any other error, you can get data with doing following changes.

Why you are getting this error? -> You have to subscribe observable to get data from it.

service.ts

```
public getStock(name: string) : Observable<Cagr[]>{
// url should be api/stock/aapl
const url = `${this.apiURL}/api/stock/${name}`;
console.log('url', url)
return this.http.get<Cagr[]>(url);
```

component

```
get(stock) {
  this.api.getStock(stock).subscribe(data => { console.log("data from backend", data); });
}
```